# Use mysql of wamp stack in stand alone php and apache installation

Tags: php, mysql, windows, apache

I am using Wampserver 2.5.My wamp server uses php5.5 but due to some extension issue i had to use php 5.3 so i installed standalone php 5.3 and apache 2.2 on my local system.I made a test.php file and echoed phpinfo() which work fine with stand alone installation but when i try to connect with mysql it show below mentioned error.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\wamp\www\development\nrg\test.php on line 12
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your PHP 5.3's php.ini file you have these two extensions loaded:

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```